# Undefined control sequence. {P_j}(x) = {y_j}\prod\limits_{\scriptstylek

Tags: equations

While writing an equation i got these errors

Undefined control sequence. {P_j}(x) = {y_j}\prod\limits_{\scriptstylek

Undefined control sequence. ...\scriptstylek = 1\hfill\atop\scriptstylek

```
\begin{equation}
    {P_j}(x) = {y_j}\prod\limits_{\scriptstylek = 1\hfill\atop\scriptstylek \ne j\hfill}^n {\frac{{x - {x_k}}}{{{x_j} - {x_k}}}} 
    \end{equation}
```

[image: that equation has to print]
equation must print like the image

Comment: give space (\scriptstylek)  like "\scriptstyle k"

Comment: Is scriptstyle even needed here? And `\substack{... \\...} ` is probably the latex method to use here, not `\atop`

Comment: @daleif - I fully agree. :-) See the answer I just posted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate source of the error is the lack of a space between `\scriptstyle` and `k`. In addition to fixing this syntax error, you may want to simplify and improve your code -- i.e., make it more "LaTeX-y" -- by

- using the `\substack` macro (provided by the `amsmath` package) to organize the material below the `\prod` symbol,
- getting rid of unneeded instructions such as `\limits`. and
- omitting lots and lots of pairs of curly braces that do nothing except generate code clutter.

The following two equations look very much alike when typeset; I hope you will agree, though, that the code for the second equation is both simpler and easier to "read" (for a human, that is).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\substack' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
{P_j}(x) = {y_j}\prod\limits_{\scriptstyle k = 1\hfill\atop\scriptstyle k \ne j\hfill}^n 
{\frac{{x - {x_k}}}{{{x_j} - {x_k}}}} 
\end{equation}

% With \substack, and with "\limits" and all non-essential curly braces removed:
\begin{equation}
P_j(x) = y_j \prod_{\substack{k = 1\\ k \ne j}}^n 
\frac{x - x_k}{x_j - x_k}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```